# WebApi 2 - Check for web.config values on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I am interested in building a startup routine for my API to check that certain configuration values in the web.config are present. If the routine does not contain values I would like to redirect to a route, log the missing configuration item and display a custom application offline page.

Any assistance in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Guard Class

```
public static class Guard
{
    public static bool ConfigurationValueExists(string key, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetAppConfig(key, string.Empty))) return true;

        ApiLogger.Log($"The configuration value {key} is not present and needs to be defined. Calling method is {caller}.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Configuration Class

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static T GetAppConfig<T>(string key, T defaultVal = default(T))
    {
        if (null == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key])
        {
            return defaultVal;
        }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)
            ? defaultVal
            : Generic.Turn(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key], defaultVal);
    }

    public static bool ConfigurationsAreInPlace()
    {
        return AssertMainApplicationConfiguration();
    }

    private static bool AssertMainApplicationConfiguration()
    {
        return Guard.ConfigurationValueExists("MyKey1");
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call `ConfigurationsAreInPlace` on the startup routine and redirect to my custom offline page.

Comment: Do you have any code written yet? If so, please share. To read keys from the web.config, you can use the ConfigurationManager class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134274(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: @MarioTacke, I provided some example code if needed. There are quite a few keys that are defined in numerous contexts so I just provided a small example of the code.

Comment: You mention redirecting to a route and displaying a custom page yet say that you are building an API using Web API. Are you building an API or a website?

Comment: It is a WebApi, the page is in the HelpPages area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create an Index Controller and use the Route Attribute of root to override what happens on the page. I then do the check if configurations are in place and issue a new response as needed.
Code if interested:

```
public class IndexController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetIndex()
    {
        string startUrl = "/help/";
        if (!Helpers.Configuration.ConfigurationsAreInPlace())
        {
            startUrl += "offline";
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        string fullyQualifiedUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(fullyQualifiedUrl + startUrl);
        return response;
    }
}
```